# UITableView - keep header label of section 0 from touching the header of the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with several sections with header titles.

I also have a main header for the table.

My problem is that the label for the header of section 0 touches the top edge of the header for that section, which is riiiiight up against the header of the whole table.  This is not an issue elsewhere, because the other sections have a small footer, so there is extra space between the other headers and the last cell in the previous section.

I can't figure out how to fix this.

Ideally, I'd just add space between the header of the table and the header of the first section, but looking at available tableview / delegate methods, that's not possible.

My second thought was to just center the header text vertically within the header. For that, I found the viewForHeaderInSection method.  I tried the following to access the label, but from here I'm stuck on how to get it vertically aligned. All of the NSTextAlignment options seem to be for horizontal alignment, and not vertical.

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *view = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)[super tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];

    // center view.textLabel

    return view;
}
```

Any tips on the best way to do this? Am I on the right track? Trying to polish up some of the UI in my app, and seeing this text rub up against the head is painful every time the table loads.

Edit- Here is a screen shot showing the issue: [image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your issue? I would suggest to move the content of section header so that you have some extra space on the top of it (perhaps transparent)

Comment: You might just want to opt for a custom UITableHeaderFooterView. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21761879/2754727

Comment: The "content" is the background of the header for the table. I've added a gradient layer to it. Adding a link to a screen shot now. Apologize for the redaction.

Comment: @pnavk The problem with that is that the header of the tableview does not have its own footer. i.e., when I set up a switch case for `tableView viewForHeaderInSection`, it will never touch the actual header of the table.

Comment: @JakeT. How are you creating your `TableHeaderView`? Is it in code? From the screenshot it almost looks like the table header is overlapping the section header

Comment: @pnavk The table header is set up on the storyboard. I'm gonna play with the sizes, but my section footers are 18 points and the section headers are 20 points right now. With that in mind, comparing the first and second section headers, it does look like the space between the first cell in section 1 and the top of the section title in the header is just slightly bigger than the remaining space between that header and the bottom of the cell above. It doesn't look overlapped to me. I don't get why there is no option to add padding between the header of the table and the beginning of the content.

Comment: @pnavk I have set the footers to 0 and confirmed that there is no overlapping between the Header of the table and the header of section 0. When there are no footers, it's similar spacing between the bottom cell of each section and the header of the section below it. The problem here is the placement of the header's label within its bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my solution ended up being to increase the height of the header of the table and add a view inside of it that I treated as the header, so the extra space was kind of like the footer of the header, if you will.

I had tried this solution but it didn't work because the frame was not properly set in my TVC's viewDidLayoutSubviews method nor viewWillAppear method. The solution to that was to just call [myView layoutIfNeeded] before calling my method to add the gradient layer.

I still think there should be a dang ol' padding value between the header of the table and the contents of the table...

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot would really help, please update your question if you can.

In the meanwhile, if I understand the problem correctly, why don't you just add some margin below the content you have in your `tableView.tableHeaderView`?

Or if this is not an option, you can make your own custom headers **without** the call to `super` from your example (but I agree `viewForHeaderInSection` is the right way to go).

**EDIT after seeing your screenshot**

Just use the `UITableViewDelegate`'s methods `viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` - here's some code that could help you get started:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 30)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(headerView.bounds, 10, 0)];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    headerLabel.text = @"Section header";
    return headerView;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30.0f;
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot.

The problem is that it's not space between the header of the section and any content in the header of the table, it's the background of the header in the table causing that the label is pressed up against. It just looks sloppy. 

I tried adding a UIView within the header of the table, changing the background of that view to be the gradient, and keeping the backgroun dof the actual header clear, but when I apply the gradient it thinks the frame of the UIVIew is massive and doesn't apply properly, even though it's in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: See my edit - keep in mind that you can return any view, even from a .xib file using autolayout etc

Comment: I used heightForHeaderInSection and set up each section, as well as titleForHeaderInSection to generate that title. That's kinda why I was trying to call [super viewForHeaderInSection] and wanted to edit that label's position - I need the formatting to match the rest of the headers still, I just want the labels centered within the header rather than touching the top of it. 

This looks like it'd work, but is going to require me to implement it for every single header to keep things uniform, when all I want is a couple pixels between the header of my table and that section 0 header.

Comment: I'd still go with this answer's approach, just do something like `if(section==0) { /* place the label a bit lower */ } else { /* mimic the default layout of section headers */ }`.